# Error with saving data in List

Tags: android

I have a function which I am using to count my linear function for points. I want to return list of all values. But I have somewhere bug and in my list was saved only one point. Could you tell me what is wrong and why in last table save only one point?
This is code:

```
private List<PointF> forumlaOfFunctionCharts(Number[] points){
    List<PointF> listOfPoints = new ArrayList<PointF>();
    PointF xy = new PointF();
    float a = 0, b = 0, y = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<points.length-1; i++){
        y1 = points[i].intValue();
        y2 = points[i+1].intValue();

        a = (y1-y2)/(i-(i+1));
        b = y1 - (a*i);

        Log.v("daneTabela", ""+a+", "+b);
        for(float j = i; j<=i+1; j=j+0.1f){
            y = a * j + b;
            xy.set(j, y);
            listOfPoints.add(xy);
            Log.v("daneTa", ""+xy.x+", "+xy.y);
        }
    }

    return listOfPoints;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move  `PointF xy = new PointF();` inside for loop to add new object  in ArrayList as :

```
 PointF xy ; 
 //..your code here...
 Log.v("daneTabela", ""+a+", "+b);
        for(float j = i; j<=i+1; j=j+0.1f){
            y = a * j + b;
             xy = new PointF();  //<<< create PointF object here
            xy.set(j, y);

            listOfPoints.add(xy);
            Log.v("daneTa", ""+xy.x+", "+xy.y);
        }
 //...your code here
```